# Unable to read anything but version information from MMA9555L

Tags: i2c, atmega328p

I'm currently working on a project that uses a MMA9555L from NXP. I'm trying to acces the chip via I2C but the only thing I can access is the version information. This gives me the impression that the chip is functioning, at least partly. Can somebody help me since I don't fully comprehend the datasheet. I'm trying to use the pedometer functionality of the chip via I2C to an Atmega328p running at 1Mhz.

Datasheet: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA9555L.pdf

Comment: What results are you getting? NACKs? Zeros? All-ones? Garbage? Electrical noise that doesn't resemble a valid SDA signal?

Comment: search for the word `example` in the datasheet

Comment: @nanofarad The return remains the same. If I unpower the chip and I ask information, I get all zero's. If I firstly request the version info, I get the version info and every command after that gives the version info.

Comment: I'm confused. I2C is an open drain bus and sits at 1 when idle. If the chip is unpowered, it shouldn't be able to drive the line low. Can you include a wavefrom from either an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer?

Comment: As @nanofarad stated, the I2C protocol uses an open-drain interface and will remain at logic 1 when the bus is idle, PROVIDED you have added external pull-up resistors to the pins on the Atmega328P chip. If not, then this could be the cause. Also, chips can actually work (somewhat) without power by stealing power from logic inputs (power bleeding), but they typically act weir and unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I've found that you have to start writes with a preceding zero byte. Adding Wire.write(0x00) before the actual command solves it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where did you find this out?

Comment: https://community.nxp.com/t5/Sensors/mma9555l-with-nrf51422-using-i2c/m-p/765330

Comment: I read the thread and don't see where it says you have to write 0x00 before sending a command. Are you referring to the sub-address ie. mailbox 0?

Comment: I derived it from the document linked by the manufacturer. It might be the sub-address.